# Is NFT swap possible on cross chains?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, nft, swaps

I have done a bit of research on this, and I have found only the same chain NFT swap but I want to know the different chain swapping b/w two users, Please provide some links or guidance to achieve NFT swapping on a different chain

Attaching is an example code of the [Swap Kiwi](https://swap.kiwi/) platform which offers NFT swapping on the same chain

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.1;

import "hardhat/console.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/IERC1155.sol";

interface ISwapKiwi {
  function proposeSwap(
      address secondUser,
      address[] memory nftAddresses,
      uint256[] memory nftIds,
      uint128[] memory nftAmounts
  ) external payable;

  function initiateSwap(
      uint64 swapId,
      address[] memory nftAddresses,
      uint256[] memory nftIds,
      uint128[] memory nftAmounts
  ) external payable;

  function cancelSwap(uint64 swapId) external;
  function cancelSwapByInitiator(uint64 swapId) external;
  function cancelSwapBySecondUser(uint64 swapId) external;
}

contract TestERC721 is ERC721("TEST", "TEST") {

  function mint(address account, uint256 tokenId) public {
      _mint(account, tokenId);
  }

  receive() external payable {}

}

contract TestERC1155 is ERC1155("TEST") {
  function mint(address account, uint256 tokenId, uint256 tokenAmount) public {
      _mint(account, tokenId, tokenAmount, "");
  }
}

contract SwapParticipant {
  address public swapContract;
  uint public counter;
  uint public counter2;

  event Received(address indexed sender, uint amount);

  function proposeSwap(
      address secondUser,
      address[] memory nftAddresses,
      uint256[] memory nftIds,
      uint128[] memory nftAmounts
  ) external payable {
      for (uint256 i = 0; i < nftAddresses.length; i++) {
          IERC1155(nftAddresses[i]).setApprovalForAll(swapContract, true);
      }
      ISwapKiwi(swapContract).proposeSwap{ value: msg.value }(secondUser, nftAddresses, nftIds, nftAmounts);
  }

  function initiateSwap(
      uint64 swapId,
      address[] memory nftAddresses,
      uint256[] memory nftIds,
      uint128[] memory nftAmounts
  ) external payable {
      for (uint256 i = 0; i < nftAddresses.length; i++) {
          IERC1155(nftAddresses[i]).setApprovalForAll(swapContract, true);
      }
      ISwapKiwi(swapContract).initiateSwap{ value: msg.value }(swapId, nftAddresses, nftIds, nftAmounts);
  }

  function cancelSwap(uint64 swapId) external {
      ISwapKiwi(swapContract).cancelSwap(swapId);
  }

  function cancelSwapByInitiator(uint64 swapId) external {
      uint balanceBefore = address(this).balance;
      ISwapKiwi(swapContract).cancelSwapByInitiator(swapId);
      uint balanceAfter = address(this).balance;
      if (balanceAfter > balanceBefore) {
          (bool success,) = payable(msg.sender).call{value: balanceAfter - balanceBefore}("");
          require(success, "Failed to send Ether to the initiator user");
      }
  }

  function cancelSwapBySecondUser(uint64 swapId) external {
      uint balanceBefore = address(this).balance;
      ISwapKiwi(swapContract).cancelSwapBySecondUser(swapId);
      uint balanceAfter = address(this).balance;
      if (balanceAfter > balanceBefore) {
          (bool success,) = payable(msg.sender).call{value: balanceAfter - balanceBefore}("");
          require(success, "Failed to send Ether to the initiator user");
      }
  }

  function setCounter(uint _counter) external {
      counter = _counter;
  }

  function setCounter2(uint _counter) external {
      counter2 = _counter;
  }

  function setSwap(address _swapAddress) external {
      swapContract = _swapAddress;
  }

  function onERC1155Received(
      address,
      address,
      uint256,
      uint256,
      bytes memory
  ) public returns (bytes4) {
      if (counter != 0) {
          revert("The malicious onERC1155Received contract");
      }
      return this.onERC1155Received.selector;
  }

  receive() external payable {
      if (counter2 != 0) {
          revert("eth transfer reverted");
      }
      emit Received(msg.sender, msg.value);
  }
}
```

I have also looked on the [Polynetwork](https://bridge.poly.network/testnet/nft) site but do not understand what are they doing.